# How to change the default View Controller that is loaded when app launches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have an application, say 'MyApp', which by default loads the view controller 'MyAppViewController' whenever the application launches. Later, I added a new view controller 'NewViewControler' to the project.

I now want the 'NewViewController' to be my default view controller which loads when the app launches.

Please let me know what changes I need to make in my project to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open `MainWindow.xib` and replace MyAppViewController with NewViewController.
2. In your app delegate class, replace the property for MyAppViewController with one for NewViewController. Connect NewViewController to its new outlet in Interface Builder.
3. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` add NewViewController's view to the window instead of MyAppViewController's view.

Comment: RE #1: I've found that if you just change the class of MyAppViewController to NewViewController, this sometimes seems to confuse Interface Builder.   My app would build, but when I ran it, it would crash, still trying to load the old View Controller type, which I had of course deleted.   I was able to fix it by deleting MyAppViewController in MainWindow.xib, then adding a View Controller and changing it's class to NewViewController, and rewiring the App Delegate outlet  to the NewViewController.   YMMV.

Answer (score 15):

Its easy, just:

- Open your Storyboard
- Click on the View Controller corresponding to the view that you want to be the initial view
- Open the Attributes Inspector
- Select the "Is Initial View Controller" check box in the View Controller section

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your main NIB file is still set to "MainWindow", check your *-Info.plist file.

If that's the case you can open the MainWindow.xib in Interface Builder. You should see a View Controller item. Bring up the inspector window and change the Class Identity to point to your new class. That should take care of instantiating your class.

As this feels like a "newbie" question (please pardon me if I'm mistaken) I would also highly recommend the following article:

[iPhone Programming Fundamentals: Understanding View Controllers](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42476)

Helped me understand the whole ViewController thing and the IB interaction..

Comment: As Ole Begemann mentions you should indeed also change the references in the AppDelegate and wire it up with IB. The linked articles also demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

As for me with xcode 4.3.3, all I had to do was simply replace all references of 'MyAppViewController' with 'NewViewController' in the AppDelegate h and m files.

Perhaps all the other steps have been taken out in the newer versions of xcode.

Hope this helps.